# I don't understand Ajax, Promise and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```
const getXHR = (type, url) => {

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
            resolve(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            reject(new Error(`Error. Code ${xhr.status}`))
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        reject(new Error(`Error. Problem with connection`));
    }

});

xhr.open(type, url);

return {xhr, p};

};

export default {

get(url) {

  var _getXHR = getXHR('GET', url),
      xhr = _getXHR.xhr,
      p = _getXHR.p;

    xhr.send();

    return p;

  }
}
```

I don't understand why I have to use this code to get it to work:

```
var _getXHR = getXHR('GET', url),
      xhr = _getXHR.xhr,
      p = _getXHR.p;
```

instead of this:

```
var xhr = getXHR('GET', url).xhr,
    p = getXHR('GET', url).p;
```

What is wrong with this? For me it is excatly the same lines of code. I would be grateful for any kind of help. Maybe someone has a link where I can find the answer?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = getXHR('GET', url).xhr,
p = getXHR('GET', url).p;
```

Creates two requests, and then gets the xhr object of the first, and the promise of the second. The xhr request of the first is *sent* , that one of the promise is always in a pending state. So thats probably not working. May use some destructuring:

```
var { p, xhr } = getXHR('GET', url);
xhr.send();
return p;
```

Comment: sorry but I still don't get it